# Can you display more than 10 items per page in steam community market

Tags: steam, steam-community-market

On the steam community market it often takes me a good few seconds for a page to load (probably my internet connection). The problem is I look at the items and then want to move onto the next page, it would be better if I could load 100 items at once and then go get a coffee as they actually load into my browser. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately at this time Steam has not integrated any features that allow the user to change how many results they can view per page.

A cheap workout is to open several tabs at once for each page of the market place. Tab 1 for items 0-10, Tab 2 for items 11-20, Tab 3 for items 21-30 and so on.

You can do this is a browser by editing the URL:

steam.steamstore.example/marketplace/#**p4**_popular_desc

"p4" denotes page 4, changing this to "p5" will load page 5.